# Canva drawImage not working in chrome use this image

Tags: canvas, drawimage

1. use chrooe
2. open devtools
3. open this page

https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-benz-44qsh2?file=/index.html

only this imgae can't render in chrome.

```
const canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        const img1 = new Image();
        img1.width = 100;
        img1.height = 100;

        // img1.referrerPolicy = 'no-referrer';

        img1.onload = (res) => {

          const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

          ctx.font = "48px serif";
          ctx.fillText("Hello world", 10, 50);
          ctx.drawImage(img1, 0, 0, 81.3, 128);

          document.body.appendChild(img1);
        };

        img1.src = 'img'
}
```

Comment: you should open devtools an Disable cache.

Comment: Oh sorry, I missed that part and I can indeed reproduce. Very strange indeed, even `createImageBitmap` has issues (from the <img> or from a fetched Blob). I'll investigate this tomorrow.

Comment: So it seems this file is missing some data at the end of the file. `jpeginfo` states "WARNING Premature end of JPEG file", and Photoshop refuses to open it "because an unexpected end-of-file was encountered." I guess Chrome is able to rebuild it somehow when they do cache it, but not when it comes fresh. That's still a weird behavior, and it may be worth a report, but the best is obviously to not use broken images.

Comment: you are right, thx!
Later, I want to continue to investigate why the img tag can be rendered

Comment: Yes, if you do open a bug report, please let me know about it. I'm also interested.